# Creating service using a minikube

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

A trying run a simples service in minikube with nginx image

I runned deployment and service using bellow commands

```
felipeflores@GMEPN004052:~$ kubectl run meu-nginx --image nginx --port 80
kubectl run --generator=deployment/apps.v1 is DEPRECATED and will be removed in a future version. Use kubectl run --generator=run-pod/v1 or kubectl create instead.
deployment.apps/meu-nginx created
felipeflores@GMEPN004052:~$ kubectl expose deployment meu-nginx
service/meu-nginx exposed
```

Was create my service correctly, but I can't access the endpoint, with port

```
felipeflores@GMEPN004052:~$ kubectl get service
NAME                TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
kubernetes          ClusterIP   10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP        55d
meu-nginx           ClusterIP   10.108.164.133   <none>        80/TCP         20m
```

But

```
felipeflores@GMEPN004052:~$ curl 10.108.164.133
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 10.108.164.133 port 80
```

For informations I put describes the service and deployment

```
felipeflores@GMEPN004052:~$ kubectl describe service meu-nginx
Name:              meu-nginx
Namespace:         default
Labels:            run=meu-nginx
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          run=meu-nginx
Type:              ClusterIP
IP:                10.108.164.133
Port:              <unset>  80/TCP
TargetPort:        80/TCP
Endpoints:         172.17.0.15:80
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>

felipeflores@GMEPN004052:~$ kubectl describe deploy meu-nginx
Name:                   meu-nginx
Namespace:              default
CreationTimestamp:      Mon, 29 Apr 2019 09:07:46 -0300
Labels:                 run=meu-nginx
Annotations:            deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: 1
Selector:               run=meu-nginx
Replicas:               1 desired | 1 updated | 1 total | 1 available | 0 unavailable
StrategyType:           RollingUpdate
MinReadySeconds:        0
RollingUpdateStrategy:  25% max unavailable, 25% max surge
Pod Template:
  Labels:  run=meu-nginx
  Containers:
   meu-nginx:
    Image:        nginx
    Port:         80/TCP
    Host Port:    0/TCP
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:       <none>
  Volumes:        <none>
Conditions:
  Type           Status  Reason
  ----           ------  ------
  Available      True    MinimumReplicasAvailable
  Progressing    True    NewReplicaSetAvailable
OldReplicaSets:  <none>
NewReplicaSet:   meu-nginx-546db5bbc9 (1/1 replicas created)
Events:
  Type    Reason             Age   From                   Message
  ----    ------             ----  ----                   -------
  Normal  ScalingReplicaSet  27m   deployment-controller  Scaled up replica set meu-nginx-546db5bbc9 to 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Service of type ClusterIP is not available from outside of Kubernetes. You need to use service type LoadBalancer or NodePort.

Please read:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/hello-minikube/#create-a-service
https://medium.com/@xcoulon/deploying-your-first-web-app-on-minikube-6e98d2884b3a

Comment: Yeah but I need acces by this IP ```felipeflores@GMEPN004052:~$ minikube status
host: Running
kubelet: Running
apiserver: Running
kubectl: Correctly Configured: pointing to minikube-vm at 192.168.39.47
```